# Quote marks broken in Sublime Text Cobalt theme comments?

Tags: themes, sublimetext, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 3 (Mac), I really like the Cobalt theme.

However, the theme seems broken.  When lines are commented out, the comments change quote marks.  Double quotes become single; Single quotes disappear altogether:
[image]
This is the same window, using the Monokai theme:
[image]
So:

- How might I fix this locally so I can stop going bananas?
- Where do I file a bug report?  [Here?](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues)  Is this a "default package"?

Comment: Yes, this is a default package, so I'd file the report there, and reference this question as well. If the other maintainers (I'm one of them) feel like it might better fit in Core, they'll just move it, but Default is probably your best bet now.

Comment: ok, I'll do that.  Thanks

Comment: bug report: https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/DefaultPackages/issues/109

Comment: now here https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/713

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with non-anti-aliased font rendering on Sublime Text, at a certain font size.  In other words, it's a very specialized problem.

Switching to an anti-aliased font fixed the problem.